# Git pull doesn’t fast-forward merge, even though there are no conflicts

Tags: git

I just performed a `git pull` from my master branch on a remote repo into the branch I'm currently working on locally via the command line.

Unexpectedly Vim opened. I quit Vim.
Following this, I checked `git status` which provided the following info:

```
On branch vod_playlists_my_list_title
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging. 
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

along with  a list of 3 files to commit.

However, I didn't resolve any conflicts. Looking at the files, I would have expected a fast-forward merge to have occurred.

Wondering what I've missed or should have done in Vim...?

Comment: You should have been save that opened vim prompt. It was you commit . I think now you try to again pull and then save whatever comes in new vim prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What happened

When you performed `git pull`, it made a merge. As it didn't have any conflicts, it tried to create a new merge-commit.

As such, it opened Vim to write a commit message.
You then quit Vim without saving, leaving the commit message empty.

Git rejected the empty commit, which left you with everything in the commit added to the staging area, but the commit still undone.

### How to fix it

You just need to do `git commit`, enter a message, and save & quit with `:wq`

Answer (score 1):

You have to commit your changes even if you did not fix any merge due to your **non-Fast forward pull (pull=fetch + merge)**.

`no-ff` creates a `merge commit` and you must run `git commit` to commit it.

---

#### Here is a demo of how it will look like.

[image]