# Git pull doesn’t fast-forward merge even though there are no file conflicts

Tags: git

Pretty much what it says on title. There were new files in the pulled commits though. Does that stop FF from happening?

Note: [Git pull doesn’t fast-forward merge, even though there are no conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019195/git-pull-doesn-t-fast-forward-merge-even-though-there-are-no-conflicts) might seem like a duplicate but the accepted answer talks about how to commit once the merge was interrupted by not saving commit message.

Comment: So what _does_ it do? Is there an error? Does it say why it wouldn't fast-forward? What specifically did you type?

Comment: It does a merge with merge commit. It opened vim with default message, I saved it and git committed the merge.

Comment: Oh, so you didn't even tell it to `--ff-only`? I assumed there was a reason you expected it to be a fast-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git only performs a fast forward merge when there are no divergent commits between the two branches. That means that the current branch is an ancestor of the one you're merging with.

If there *are* divergent commits, it does not matter whethere there are conflicts or not. Git still has to store the merge as a new commit.

From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging):

> [...] when you try to merge one commit with a commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward because there is no divergent work to merge together – this is called a “fast-forward.”

Comment: Do you mean to say FF will take place only if I pull without committing anything?

Comment: @Akilan Exactly. FF happens if there are no commits in the current branch that do not exist in the other branch.